# Error in using Speech to text functionality in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, speech-to-text

I am trying to use "speech-to-text" functionality in xamarin ios. But I am getting following error after adding "Using Speech;" in my class file.

*Your application is using the 'Speech' framework, which isn't included in the iOS SDK you're using to build your app (this framework was introduced in iOS 10.0.0, while you're building with the iOS 10.0 SDK.) This configuration is only supported with the legacy registrar (pass --registrar:legacy as an additional mtouch argument in your project's iOS Build option to select). Alternatively select a newer SDK in your app's iOS Build options.*

How I can use "Speech" in xamarin ios app?

Comment: whats your deployment target

Comment: my deployment target is 10.0

Comment: are you intergarated the speech frame work in your app

Comment: are you added the legacy registrar in your plist

Comment: Yes I am trying to add speech framework in my app. No I didn't add legacy registrat. How do we add it?

Comment: see this https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/PlatformFeatures/SpeechToText/

Comment: The url you give is for android. I need fo xamarin ios.

Comment: bro , take a loot at steps only dont focucs on domain

Answer (score 0):

Check your Xcode version first. Whether is the latest version.

Check also **iOS project Options->iOS Build->SDK Version**, whether is using correct SDK version. For mine, it is set to Default which is 10.3 now.

[image]